# Sliders in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to create a slider in PowerBI just like we create a slider in EXCEL.If possible can someone point me to some basic tutorials for that or may e an example would really help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think OP is referring to a slider in the context of having a slicer with variable values that can be adjusted by dragging a button of some type along a bar with beginning and ending values, such as a date.  Power BI added a date slider in a recent update which is accessed by choosing the slicer visual in your screenshot and selecting a date field from the query.  There is also a custom visual which allows granularity from year to quarter to month to week to day.  The beginning of the fiscal year can be customized in the formatting options, so it's pretty useful if one is using Power BI in a business setting.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any other type of slider available which allows the use of fields other than ones which contain date values.  Even when the field is a date/time value, neither of the sliders have the ability to show hours/minutes/seconds.  I was searching for one I could use with time or even on an index column when I saw this question and haven't had much luck.

Comment: Your answer is as much an assumption as mine. No need to downvote mine, therefore. There are lots of threads here where people make that typo for slicer. The OP never clarified, so how can you be so sure?